# How to spy on a default exported function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

sinon.spy takes 2 parameters, object and function name.

I have a module as listed below:

`module.exports = function xyz() { }`

How do I define a spy for `xyz`? I don't have object name to use.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 55):

The above actually doesn't work if you're using the ES6 modules import functionality, If you are I've discovered you can actually spy on the defaults like so.

```
// your file
export default function () {console.log('something here');}

// your test
import * as someFunction from './someFunction';
spyOn(someFunction, 'default')
```

As stated in [http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#the-default-export-is-just-another-named-export)

> The default export is actually just a named export with the special name default

So the import * as someFunction gives you access to the whole module.exports object allowing you to spy on the default.

Comment: anyone found a way to do this using module.exports ?

Comment: @PimHeijden Check out module [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire). And a nice blog post on [how to use it](https://toucantoco.com/en/tech-blog/tech/spy-and-rewire-in-test).

Comment: This will not work, the default property of the exported module is not writable.