# Jest spyOn a function not Class or Object type

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jestjs

I am familiar with setting spies on Class or Object methods, but what about when the function is just an export default - such that the method itself is independent, like a utility?

I have some existing code like so:

```
const Funct1 = props => {
  if(props){
    Funct2(args);
  }
  // or return something
};
const Funct2 = props => {
  // do something
  return true
};
export default Funct1;  //Yes the existing export is named the same as the "entry" method above.
```

And, for example, I'd like to spy on `Funct1` getting called and `Funct2` returns true.

```
import Funct1 from "../../../src/components/Funct1";
describe("Test the Thing", () => {
    it("New Test", () => {
        let props = {
            active: true,
            agentStatus: "online"
        };
        const spy = spyOn(Funct2, "method name"); <-- how doe this work if not an obj or class?

        Funct1(props);
        //If I try Funct2(props) instead, terminal output is "Funct2 is not defined"

        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(props);
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to spy on a default exported function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891606/how-to-spy-on-a-default-exported-function)

Comment: I noticed this had no accepted answer. Just fyi, I tried to `import * as functions` and then create a `const spy = jest.spyOn(functions, 'name')` -- but that did not work for me.

Answer (score 28):

I am not expert in jest, but my recommendation to think about:

1) When the function is exported as default I use something like:

```
import Funct1 from "../../../src/components/Funct1";
...
jest.mock("../../../src/components/Funct1");
...
expect(Funct1).toHaveBeenCalledWith(params);
```

2) When the module (utils.js) has multiple exports as

```
export const f1 = () => {};
...
export const f8 = () => {};
```

You can try

```
import * as Utils from "../../../src/components/utils"
const f8Spy = jest.spyOn(Utils, 'f8');
...
expect(f8Spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(params);
```

[Similar discussion here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1414#issuecomment-393817117)

Comment: I get ` TypeError: Cannot redefine property: env` for #2

Comment: It is worthwhile to check out this answer where it is shown how to mock only certain code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402206/2239549

Answer (score 11):

Wrap your function with `jest.fn`. Like this:

```
const simpleFn = (arg) => arg;
const simpleFnSpy = jest.fn(simpleFn);
simpleFnSpy(1);
expect(simpleFnSpy).toBeCalledWith(1); // Passes test
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Jest requires mocks to be inside an Object or Class, but if they aren't like that in your code, you can still put them there in the test:

```
jest.mock('../pathToUtils', () => ({
  func2: jest.fun().mockImplementation((props) => "ok") //return what you want
  otherfuncs: ...etc
}));

const mockUtils = require('../pathToUtils')
const func1 = require('./pathToFunc1')
```

Then in the test:

```
func1()  // call the main function

expect(mockUtils.func2).toHaveBeenCalled
expect(mockUtils.func2).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
expect(mockUtils.func2).toHaveBeenCalledWith(arg1, arg2, etc)
expect(mockUtils.func2).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(arg1, arg2, etc)
```

You'll have already done unit testing of the Util function in another file, so you won't actually be running the function again here, this is just mocking for the purpose of the integration testing.

Answer (score -5):

I believe that is not possible to test Funct1 calling Funct2 without modifying the existing code. If the latter is an option, here are two options to introduce dependency injection:

- Create and export a factory function:

  ```
  const Funct2 = props => {
      // do something
      return true;
  };
  const Funct1 = CreateFunct1(Funct2);
  export function CreateFunct1(Funct2) {
      return props => {
          if (props) {
              Funct2(props);
          }
          // or return something
      };
  }
  export default Funct1;  

  // and here is the test:

  describe('Test the Thing', () => {
      it('New Test', () => {
          // Arrange
          const funct2Spy = jasmine.createSpy('Funct2');
          const funct1 = CreateFunct1(funct2Spy);
          const props = "some data";

          // Act
          funct1(props);

          // Assert
          expect(funct2Spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(props);
      });
  });
  ```
- Export Funct2 too. Here is a [thread](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1149) on this topic. Maybe its example would have to be tweaked a little bit for your scenario because of the export syntax.

Comment: Question is about jest not jasmine